# Telebot - Check if the bot is admin on a channel

Tags: python, telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

I need to check if the bot is admin on a channel. I'm using the library pyTelegramBotAPI.

I tried with this:

```
bot.get_chat_member(msg.forward_from_chat.id, '@TestBot')
```

but it gives me this error:

> [b'{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: wrong user_id specified"}']"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, I figured out why it wasn't working. The user_id parameter is meant to be for an `int`, so putting the username of the bot is not working. To fix, just get the ID of the bot using something like @getidsbot and put the ID as parameter `user_id` in the `method get_chat_member()`